# Xibo upgrade from 2.3.16 to 3.0.0

Tags: content-management-system, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade Xibo digital signage from version 2.3.16 to 3.0.0 (and 3.3.3). My database is updated to 5.7 and it was working with 2.3.16 but after upgrade i have this error from logs:

xibo-cms-web-1 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'pid' doesn't have a default value

I could not find any solution to this.
Help please

Answer (score 1):

I manage to upgrade to 3.0.3.
First, if you are upgrading from 5.6 to 5.7 of mysql database (after upgrade):

```
> docker compose down
>     docker run --rm -ti -v /opt/xibo/shared/db:/var/lib/mysql mysql:5.7 bash
>     mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
>     mysql_upgrade (just type the command, you wont see a cursor)
>     exit
```

Download the new version of xibo (in my case 3.0.3) and add to your yml file:

```
> command: mysqld 
--sql_mode=‘ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION’
```

in cms-db.

Now I have to upgrade all the way up to 3.3.3